# Is there any way to get Guice Grapher to work?

Tags: java, graph, dependency-injection, visualization, guice

There's a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=663) in the Guice grapher utility that causes most or all graphs to render corrupted.  Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I modified @wuppi's answer slightly to also hide class paths and long random name annotations to make the graph much more compact and readable.  His [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229158/403455) with edited code follows:

I find this utility method pretty useful and it never pritned incorrect graphs for me.

Regarding the `style=invis` bug: The Guice grapher plugin generates a dot file, which styles some of the clases as invisible. The `replaceAll()` in the below posted method works around that. The rest of the code is nearly the same from the Guice example.

I've incorporated Scot's fix for Guice 4.x, which included Tim's answer as well:

```
public class Grapher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Grapher.graph4("filename.dot", Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()));
    }
    public static void graph4(String filename, Injector inj) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(baos);

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GraphvizModule());
        GraphvizGrapher renderer = injector.getInstance(GraphvizGrapher.class);
        renderer.setOut(out);
        renderer.setRankdir("TB");
        renderer.graph(inj);    

        out = new PrintWriter(new File(filename), "UTF-8");
        String s = baos.toString("UTF-8");
        s = fixGrapherBug(s);
        s = hideClassPaths(s);
        out.write(s);
        out.close();
    }

    public static String hideClassPaths(String s) {
        s = s.replaceAll("\\w[a-z\\d_\\.]+\\.([A-Z][A-Za-z\\d_\\$]*)", "$1");
        s = s.replaceAll("value=[\\w-]+", "random");
        return s;
    }

    public static String fixGrapherBug(String s) {
        s = s.replaceAll("style=invis", "style=solid");
        s = s.replaceAll("margin=(\\S+), ", " margin=\"$1\", ");
        return s;
    }
}
```

Of course you are free to generate any other Filename :)

Comment: Jeff, I don't know if you saw @Tim's answer but it's needed for the latest version of graphviz and Guice 3.0. I didn't try it with 4.0 beta yet.

Answer (score 5):

Guice 4.x example incorporating Jeff and Tim's solutions:

```
public class Grapher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Grapher.graph4("filename.dot", Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()));
    }
    public static void graph4(String filename, Injector inj) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(baos);

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GraphvizModule());
        GraphvizGrapher renderer = injector.getInstance(GraphvizGrapher.class);
        renderer.setOut(out);
        renderer.setRankdir("TB");
        renderer.graph(inj);    

        out = new PrintWriter(new File(filename), "UTF-8");
        String s = baos.toString("UTF-8");
        s = fixGrapherBug(s);
        s = hideClassPaths(s);
        out.write(s);
        out.close();
    }

    public static String hideClassPaths(String s) {
        s = s.replaceAll("\\w[a-z\\d_\\.]+\\.([A-Z][A-Za-z\\d_]*)", "");
        s = s.replaceAll("value=[\\w-]+", "random");
        return s;
    }

    public static String fixGrapherBug(String s) {
        s = s.replaceAll("style=invis", "style=solid");
        s = s.replaceAll("margin=(\\S+), ", " margin=\"$1\", ");
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small bug fix -- in the current version of guice-grapher that I am using (4.0-beta), the 'margin' keyword doesn't have a space in front of it, so the replacement line should be: s = s.replaceAll("margin=(\\S+), ", " margin=\"$1\", ");  Otherwise, thank you very much for the sample.

Answer (score 2):

When using the most recent version of GraphViz, I find that the following substitution also helps (otherwise GraphViz refuses to open the file):

```
s.replaceAll(" margin=(\\S+), ", " margin=\"$1\", ")
```

Answer (score -1):

The first replaceAll in the hideClassPaths() method above is over zealous -- it removes the class name as well as the package. It should be

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\w[a-z\\d_\\.]+\\.([A-Z][A-Za-z\\d_\\$]*)", "$1");
```

Note the addition of the dollar-sign so this also works for internal class names.

Comment: Thanks! Please delete this answer and either comment on or edit the incorrect answer.